# Operaciones listas enlazadas

Tags: c++, c

1. Estoy con el tema de las listas enlazadas. En especial con la lista simplemente enlazada. He visto las tipicas operaciones que se pueden hacer con este tipo de estructuras: añadir por el principio, por el final, eliminar nodos, mostrar la lista, buscar elementos etc. Sin embargo, hacer cosas como añadir por el principio de la lista en una lista simplemente enlazada verdaderamente estariamos hablando de una lista simplemente enlazada o de otro tipo de listas como las doblemente enlazadas?

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

   En una lista simplemente enlazada cada nodo apunta al siguiente y el ultimo apunta a NULL por lo que la unica operacion que podria realizar para añadir elementos seria insertar por el final de la lista o no? ya que si añado por el inicio ya no estariamos hablando de una lista simplemente enlazada.
2. Por otro lado, que operaciones se pueden realizar con una lista circular siplemente enlazada que con una lista simplemente enlazada no se pueden?

   Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

1) Aunque puedas añadir nodos por el principio de una lista, seguirá siendo una lista simplemente enlazada (LSE). ¿Pq? Por su propia definición: "*una lista simplemente enlazada es aquella en la que **cada nodo** posee un puntero al nodo siguiente, excepto el último, que es NULL*".

Lo que comentas de operaciones al principio o final de listas no circulares se utiliza para ayudar o facilitar ciertas operaciones. De hecho, podrías implementar más nodos auxiliares si lo necesitas. Imagina que estás implementando un diccionario de miles de personas (registros ordenados alfabéticamente). Si quieres insertar un nuevo nodo en la LSE será más fácil consultar la letra, por ejemplo, "S", y buscar su posición correcta a partir de dicho nodo en lugar de tener que recorrer todos los anteriores.

2) En una lista circular simplemente enlazada (LCSE) se pueden realizar las mismas operaciones, ya que el único puntero que se suele referenciar es el último, de esa manera podemos insertar un nuevo nodo final o incluso si avanzamos al siguiente del último, estaríamos en el primero, y podríamos insertar al principio de la lista (circular).

Si alguna cosa no ha quedado clara, deja tu pregunta en los comentarios.

Comment: Hola, "una lista doblemente enlazada es aquella en la que cada nodo posee dos punteros, uno al nodo anterior y otro al nodo siguiente". pero esto es una doblemente enlazada no simplemente enlazada

Comment: Lapsus, disculpa, edito y actualizo la respuesta :-) Gracias @ivan5